# Refresh Embedded PDF with Angular on Chromium

Tags: angular, pdf, chromium

my goal is to build a info screen, showing a PDF File and some detail information beside this.

The Idea is to have some screen with a Raspberry Pi running FullpageOS attached. FullpageOS boots the Pi and starts a chromium Browser in kiosk mode.

I builded a page showing the details plus a fixed PDF with Angular and it looked good on my FullpageOS test system.
I displayed the PDF by using the embedded HTML Tag to call the buildin PDF renderer.

```
<embed src="./PDF/My.pdf#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&view=FitV" class="clientheight" width="100%" />
```

The problem occurs when I try to change the PDF dynamically.
I use a sanitizer to get a save URL and bind the src to my Variable holding the save URL:

```
  <embed [src]="PdfURL" class="clientheight" width="100%" />

  private getSaveURL(url: string) {
    url += "#toolbar=0&navpanes=0&scrollbar=0&view=FitV";
    this.PdfURL = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustResourceUrl(url);
  }
```

This code works on FireFox with the exception that the toolbar is not hidden but it fails on Chromium (and edge).
The chromium browser simply shows noting until I move the Browser Window from one Screen to another. After I change the PdfUrl again nothing will happen even with moving of the Windows.

I’m looking for a way to make Chromium to refresh the PDF after I changed the PdfURL value.

Answer (score 0):

in [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23681394/11806485) I found the hint to embedd the embedded tag into an object tag for better browser compatibility. So I tried it and it solved the probrem.
Changing my html code to:

```
<object [data]="PdfURL" type="application/pdf" class="clientheight" width="100%">
    <embed [src]="PdfURL" type="application/pdf"/>
</object>
```

does the trick.